# The sqlite database insert duplicated data

Tags: android, sqlite

I got the data from webservice and insert them to database in activity onCreate() function. the code is as below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_person);

    RunningService runningService = new RunningService();
    runningService.insert(staff);
    initView();
}
```

And the the code of insert() is as below:

```
public void insertAllStaff(Staff staff){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", staff.getName());
    Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Every time that I go into this activity, it will insert data to database, the data are the same.

Is there a method that I can go into this activity and it doesn't insert the same data to database?

Comment: Check if there is same data, and then only insert into it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want repeated values for your table you have to define a UNIQUE index for the field you feel is "unique".

You do that at table CREATE time, or you can create indexes using the ALTER SQL statement.

Comment: And I guess exception is thrown when non-unique data is tried to insert. +1 from me

Comment: I would advise if possible to resolve this without unique constraint violations and throwing exceptions.
As I see it, exceptions should not occur often, and if the data being retrieved from the WebService contains redundant info, we should think of a solution how to handle that without exceptions.

Comment: @MarkSkayff answer it ok, and i am agree, you should use a constraint unique for your PK. But however, whatching your code, it dont have to insert two repeated values. The only ask i will make to you is, the inserts are twice?, if yes, probably you have something bad in another place that must fix. Otherwise, adding the unique constraint will fix that. Recards

Comment: @Max Pinto when i came back to this activity, it would call onCreat(), and it would insert the data again, i only need it insert the data for the first time to this activity, how can i do this?

Comment: @Eric Cheng, you probably need to check for the existance and state of the record in the database before you insert a new one then. If your app is doing some sort of initialization, you should read the data first, and if present (or equal) you then avoid re-inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports the INSERT NOT EXISTS syntax.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(id,text) 
SELECT 123, 'Helloworld' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 123 FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123');
```

Please use this syntax for performance. 
Which content provider are you using with your resolver? You might need to change it and use something else which uses the above SQL statement.

Comment: OK, I will try this method